# What to do when the selenium click function is flaky

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

Has anyone had trouble using the selenium click function? Sometimes it cannot click on an element even though its visible. Sometimes it can click on an element that is underneath another element (that the user cannot click on).  What's a good alternative?

Comment: make sure your locator (xpath) is always right, do a proper synchronization (wait for element rather than find it, similar to answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074172/how-can-i-check-until-an-element-is-clickable-using-nightwatchjs). Sometimes it's also necessary to bring the page to certain position (using browser.getLocationInView for example), so that the element is not overlapped by anything else

Comment: i got that problem too, sometime client moveto() element instead of clicking it